# Motorola XOOM / Tablet manifest

Tags: android, flash, air

Could anyone please post a complate template/sample of a Motorola XOOM manifest.

I am creating an application using Flash/Air - How do I  ensure the app can only be run on a tablet ?

This is what i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">
    <id>Reverse domain format</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
    <filename></filename>
    <description></description>
    <!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.
    <description>
        <text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text>
        <text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text>
        <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text>
    </description>
    -->
    <name></name>
    <!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.
    <name>
        <text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text>
        <text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text>
        <text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text>
    </name>
    -->
    <copyright>Name</copyright>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>Invaders_Final.swf</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
        <aspectRatio>landscape or portrait</aspectRatio>
        <renderMode>gpu or cpu</renderMode>
    </initialWindow>
    <customUpdateUI>false or true</customUpdateUI>
    <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
    <icon>
        <image36x36>icon36.png</image36x36>
        <image48x48>icon48.png</image48x48>
        <image72x72>icon72.png</image72x72>
    </icon>
    <android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/></manifest>
]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
    <versionLabel></versionLabel>
</application>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what the actual criteria you want to enforce are - flash support?  a screen size?  an api version?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="11"
           />
```

Comment: That's only going to work until there's another phone-oriented Android release.

Comment: @Chris Could you elaborate, please? There is no `maxSdkVersion` here.

Comment: exactly, because there is no maximum version, a future "phone" running a post honeycomb release would accept this, and the poster wants to limit to tablets.  Perhaps the question is mis-stated, and "tablets" are not really the criteria.